# Have workbook save without dialogbox popping up to ask save as

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet (QT) that gets filled in by the user and when the user closes the workbook a UserForm appears before closing. The user then selects a few things and the code runs. The code inserts data into another workbook (Log). My problem is the other workbook (Log) asks the user if they would like to save. I need for this step to be skipped. I have tried `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` but it does not prevent it from popping up.

```
Private Sub OKBTN_Click()
Dim TOTALFOB As String
Dim TOTALWC As String
Dim MFG As String
Dim JOB As String
Dim XL As Excel.Application
Dim wbk As Excel.Workbook
Dim INWBK As Excel.Workbook
Dim TOTMFG As Variant
Dim TOTWC As Variant
Dim visitdate As Date
Dim visitdate_text As String


TOTALFOB = RefEdit1
TOTALWC = RefEdit2
Set XL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set INWBK = ActiveWorkbook
Set wbk = XL.Workbooks.Open("C:\QUOTE REQUEST LOG 2015.xlsm")

If YESBTN.Value = True Then TOTMFG = INWBK.Sheets("QTR").Range(TOTALFOB).Value
If YESBTN.Value = True Then TOTWC = INWBK.Sheets("QTR").Range(TOTALWC).Value

If NOBTN.Value = True Then TOTMFG = "N/A"
If NOBTN.Value = True Then TOTWC = "N/A"

MFG = INWBK.Sheets("QTR").Range("B7").Value
JOB = INWBK.Sheets("QTR").Range("H13").Value
visitdate = INWBK.Sheets("QTR").Range("H9").Value
visitdate_text = Format$(visitdate, "mm\-dd\-yyyy")

wbk.Sheets("QTR_LOG").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = INWBK.Sheets("QTR").Range("B7").Value

wbk.Sheets("QTR_LOG").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1) = INWBK.Sheets("QTR").Range("H11").Value
wbk.Sheets("QTR_LOG").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 3) = INWBK.Sheets("QTR").Range("H13").Value

wbk.Sheets("QTR_LOG").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 4) = TOTMFG
wbk.Sheets("QTR_LOG").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 5) = TOTWC
wbk.Sheets("QTR_LOG").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 6) = "OPEN"

wbk.Sheets("QTR_LOG").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 7) = INWBK.Sheets("QTR").Range("H9").Value


Application.DisplayAlerts = False
INWBK.SaveAs Filename:="C:\. QUOTE REQUESTS" & _
"\DCS QTR " & MFG & " " & " " & JOB & " " & visitdate_text & ".xlsx", _
FileFormat:=51, CreateBackup:=False, local:=True


Set XL = Nothing
Unload Me
wbk.Close
End Sub
```

Code from output file (Workbook Log):

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

try ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
Even if the workbook is not saved, excel will act as if it was saved

Comment: I inserted this code into my output file and it ran correctly but did not save the data.

Comment: As I said, wasn't this what you asked?

Comment: Sorry ya that is what my title says. I will reword it. What I'm trying to do is have it save but not have the dialog pop up to ask you to save.

Comment: combine both: ThisWorkbook.Save: ThisWorkbook.Saved = True. However if your workbook has never been saved before, use ThisWorkbook.Saveas and give an output path